# Is it possible to determine logon and unlock types in windows?

Tags: c#, windows-services, smartcard

I'm working on the windows service using C#, and have to determine if a user used username and password or smartcard to logon and/or unlock PC. I found that it is possible to determine if user logon with a smartcard, but how to understand if he or she used smartcard to unlock windows?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706746/verify-windows-log-in-via-smart-card, the answer seems to be a no.

Comment: Don't you think that Windows should store some logs about logon type?